# Add username to URL with AuthenticationForm FormView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm coming from Laravel and new to Django.  I'm trying to add a username to the url after login.  This has been asked before a few times, but I have yet to make the solutions work (they involve having a model attached to the generic FormView class).  Here is what I have:

#### urls.py

```
path('login/', views.Login.as_view(), name='login'),

# Logged in user
path('home/<str:username>', views.UserIndex.as_view(), name='user_index'),
```

#### views.py

```
class Login(views.AnonymousRequiredMixin, views.FormValidMessageMixin, generic.FormView):
    authenticated_redirect_url = '/'
    form_class = LoginForm
    form_valid_message = "You have successfully logged in"
    template_name = 'pythonmodels/registration/login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pythonmodels:user_index', args=("Bill",))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(self.request, user)
            return super(Login, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

#### forms.py

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'username',
            'password',
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('login', 'Login', css_class='btn-primary')
            )
        )
```

In the `views.py` file, I would like the `args` for `success_url` to be the username of the user that was just authenticated.  Should this be done in the `LoginForm` class?  I have also seen that you can go to an intermediate url and then get the User data, but this seems like a terrible extra step.  I would like to keep this as close to the base `FormView` and `AuthenticationForm` as I don't understand more in-depth customization yet.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set `success_url` in the view, because you don't know the argument until after the user has been logged in.

Override `get_success_url` instead:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('pythonmodels:user_index', args=[self.request.user.username])
```

Comment: In Laravel, you do a simple `dump` call in a controller to print objects, variables, requests, etc. at different points in the request which get printed at the top of the webpage.  Can you do something similar with `django`?  like print `self.request` below `def get_success_url(self):` to see what it contains at that point.

Comment: Django is Python so you can use `print(dir(self.request))` to introspect it. Note that the Django class based views do not normally store attributes on `self.request` - you access the user in this way because `login()` has set it.

Comment: Great thank you, I see the `print` output in the server console